# Add an image to cover all underlying divs on a horizontally scrolling page section

Tags: html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I have a page that essentially behaving as I want it, except that I would like to place an image every so often along a horizontal scroll track. This JS Fiddle shows the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/bretwhiteley/39cLc0vm/

So what I am trying to do is add an image that is the height of the "Scrolling" DIV 1000px from the left.  I tried to use the following code, with no luck:

```
<div class="Timeline_Break" style="margin-left:1000px;">
                <div style="margin-left:1000px"><img src="http://s.w-x.co/TWC_logo_100x100.gif" style="width:20px;height:130px"></div>
            </div>
```

The Styling is:

```
.Timeline_Break {

          position: fixed;
          z-index: 99;

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

test this code

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39cLc0vm/6/)

```
<div id="Header">
    Google Chart ...
</div>

<div id="Map">Map</div>



<div id="Footer">
    <div id="FooterLeft">

        <div class="Timeline_Title">Industry</div>
        <div class="Timeline_Title">Infrastructure</div>
        <div class="Timeline_Title">Individuals</div>


    </div>

    <div id="FooterRight">
        <div id="Scrolling">

            <div class="Timeline_Banner">

                <div style="margin-left:400px;"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-J07989,_Berlin,_Sportpalast,_Waffen-SS-Angeh%C3%B6rige.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px">
                </div>

            </div>

            <div class="Timeline_Banner">

                <div style="margin-left:700px"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-J07989,_Berlin,_Sportpalast,_Waffen-SS-Angeh%C3%B6rige.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="Timeline_Banner">
                <div style="margin-left:200px"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-J07989,_Berlin,_Sportpalast,_Waffen-SS-Angeh%C3%B6rige.jpg" style="width:20px;height:20px">
                </div>
            </div>

                <div style="color:red;position:relative">
                    <div style="color:blue;position:absolute;top:0px;left:500px"><img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d2/Bundesarchiv_Bild_183-J07989,_Berlin,_Sportpalast,_Waffen-SS-Angeh%C3%B6rige.jpg" style="width:20px;height:130px">  
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>


</div>
```

Comment: = thanks for the response.  I dont want to add another horizontal bar, but rather, to add a vertical image 1000px along the existing horizontal bars to denote a section change.  Make sense?

Comment: does not clear question.test new code??Did you mean?

Comment: Seyed - I dont think I am being clear.  Rather than add a small icon (20x20) can you add one that would stretch the height of that "Scroller" div (130px)?

Comment: i add new image in right of `FooterRight` with height:130px

Comment: Seyed - did you add this to the original JS Fiddle you provided above?

Comment: Thanks for sticking with this - but that is still not it - need to add it not at the end of the div (4000px) but in the middle; at say 500 or 1000px [for example]

Comment: Yes Seyed - Yes, that was it.  Would you mind re posting that last JS Fiddle as an answer - not a question?  Be simpler for others to find that way.